# Testing laravel api with jwt

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-6

I'm trying to write some test , the first test  its for login route, I'm using `jwt` and `mongodb`, I set `.env.testing` identical to `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

this is phpunit.xml

```
 <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
 </php>
```

I tried with  `<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mongodb/>` but I get the same error

and this is the test

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_if_login()
    {
        $response = $this->json('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth', [
            'email' => 'usuario1',
            'password' => '12345'
        ]);
        
        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                'data'=>[
                    'token'
                ]
            ]);
    }
}
```

but I get this error

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\AuthTest::test_if_login
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Not sure about what is the problem

Comment: You received 500 HTTP code so you need to check log file to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: A common approach for debugging 500 errors in tests, is to dd($exception) in Exceptions\Handler.php render() function